# Casting with Generic Types

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm pretty sure there is a simple answer to this that revolves around co-variance but I'm struggling to see it!

I have a class like so:

```
internal sealed class GenericCallbackClass<T> : SomeBaseClass
    where T : ICallbackMessageBase
{
    public GenericCallbackClass(string activeId, T message)
        : base(activeId)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public T Message { get; private set; }
}
```

I then create an instance of a class that implements ICallbackMessageBase called Foo and instantiate a new GenericCallbackClass passing this in as the argument for T
e.g. `var myCallback = new GenericCallback<Foo>("SomeID", new Foo())`

I now want to cast this to a more generic instance of the GenericCallbackClass because I will have many instances of this with Foo, Bar etc but all implement ICallbackMessageBase.

So I want to do something like `var callback = myCallback as GenericCallbackClass<ICallbackMessageBase>`

It appears I can't do this cast... Any ideas how I should get around this?

Comment: search "co- and contra-variance", it is a lot of questions here on SO like yours.

Comment: Why are you even using generics here? Why isn't the class non-generic, with `ICallbackMessageBase Message`?

Comment: @svick ditto... was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need Generic `<T>`'s at all in this situation. Is there some other code in your GenericCallback class that leverages `<T>`. Otherwise you can just rely on the interface implementation of each object and ensure that the Interface defines any common properties or operations you may need in your Callback class.

```
public class SomeBaseClass 
{
   public SomeBaseClass (string activeId) 
   {
       //Persist activeId
   }
}

public interface ICallbackMessageBase { /* implementation */ } 
public class Foo : ICallbackMessageBase { /* implementation */ } 

internal sealed class GenericCallbackClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public GenericCallbackClass(string activeId, ICallbackMessageBase message)
        : base(activeId)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public ICallbackMessageBase Message { get; private set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var specific = new GenericCallbackClass("foo", new Foo());
}
```

Comment: I think your code doesn't do what you think it does. Type parameters are usually named `T` or something like that, but you have one named `ICallbackMessageBase`. That's very confusing, because that type parameter has not relation with the actual interface type `ICallbackMessageBase`. You should remove that type parameter completely.

Comment: jeepers. completely missed that. hacked it together in  LinqPad with no syntax highlighting and just blindly copypasta'd those :\

Comment: Err...sheepishly now wondering why I introduced generics myself. I'll have to put it down to one of those days! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an intermediate base class?

```
internal class GenericCallbackClassBase
{
    public GenericCallbackClassBase(ICallbackMessageBase message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public ICallbackMessageBase Message { get; private set; }
}
```

You can then derive the generic version from that:

```
internal sealed class GenericCallbackClass<T> : GenericCallbackClassBase
where T : ICallbackMessageBase
{
    public GenericCallbackClass(T message)
        : base(message) { }

    public new T Message
    {
        get { return (T)base.Message; }
    }
}
```

It's basically just a wrapper that adds type checking and automatic casting for the message property. You will then be able to do this:

```
var g = new GenericCallbackClass<A>(a);
var g2 = g as GenericCallbackClassBase;
```

The `g.Message` property will be of type `A`, whereas the `g2.Message` property will be of type `ICallbackMessageBase`.